# Vagrant complaining virtual box isn't installed when it is

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, virtualbox, vagrant

I've installed virtual box 4.1.6 and vagrant-0.8.8 on my mac osx 10.6 box.  When I run vagrant it complains that virtual box isn't installed.  Any idea how I tell vagrant where virtual box is?

This is how I've installed everything:

vagrant:

```
$ sudo gem install vagrant
Successfully installed vagrant-0.8.8
```

virtual box gem:

```
$ sudo gem install virtualbox
Successfully installed virtualbox-0.9.2
```

virtual box itself:

```
$ curl -O http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.1.6/VirtualBox-4.1.6-74713-OSX.dmg
```

.. installed via GUI ...

```
$ /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VirtualBox --help | grep Manager
Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 4.1.6
```

and finally, the error Virtualbox is giving:

```
$ vagrant
Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed.
If VirtualBox is installed, it may be an incorrect version. Vagrant currently
requires VirtualBox 4.1.x. Please install the proper version to continue.

If you have an older or newer version of VirtualBox, please make sure you're
using the proper version of Vagrant. Ask the mailing list if you have questions.
```

I've grep'ed through the virtualbox gem for any paths:

```
$ grep -R "Contents/MacOS" *
lib/virtualbox/com/ffi_interface.rb:          lib_path ||= "/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxXPCOMC.dylib"
lib/virtualbox/lib.rb:            @@lib_path = Dir.glob("/Applications/{,MacPorts/}VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxXPCOMC.dylib")
test/virtualbox/lib_test.rb:      result = ["/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxXPCOMC.dylib"]
```

This file does exist on my system:

```
$ ls -alh /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxXPCOMC.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    93K  4 Nov 12:38 /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxXPCOMC.dylib
```

I've seen this issue on github: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/562 which has other people within the past two weeks with this issue.  It mentions the previous person's version of the vargrant gem was out of date but I'm using 0.8.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by running vagrant with sudo :

```
sudo vagrant
```

Comment: that might mean that your user has not been added to the vboxusers group - which you need to do manually

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why chmod a+rx wasn't enough but that's working.  Thanks.